# How do I mix MVC pages with non-MVC (i.e. straight HTML) pages on the same site?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.net so this is probably obvious to others who use it all the time. How do I mix MVC pages with straight HTML pages? Only about 10% of my website pages need the business logic and database connectivity that MVC affords, the rest are just pages with static text/graphic information. I don't want to create controllers and views for these static pages if I don't need to. Do I put the static .html pages in a different separate folder from the .cshtml pages and then route to them based on the folder or extension? An example would be very helpful please. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably no point in wrapping access to the static pages using controllers/actions. I would just leave them as static html pages if there is no need for server side logic to render them.